# Gather IP address information

Tags: powershell, windows-7, ip-address

I'm struggling to find info on differences between the PowerShell versions, but it's all pretty mixed up.

What commands are there available for network commands in PowerShell 3 installed on Windows 7? As far as I've read, many modules need to be imported separately, but I couldn't find any for the `get-netipaddress` cmdlet, or others similar, that are available in Win8 or Win Server 2012, but not on win7. Is there a module that can be imported in Win7 for it? Perhaps there is a similar command in PS v2?

Update: I'm running v3. And from what I've read, that command is available on PowerShell 3, but not installed on Win7. But why would that be the case?

[image]

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need those cmdlets for?

Comment: Well, for now, mostly for my studies. I'm following some examples that actually use v.3 (supposedly) on a windows server 2012. I don't have access to that now, so i installed it on the Win 7 laptop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PowerShell releases only ship with a "core" set of cmdlets, and it's only that set of cmdlets that are altered when you install a new version of PowerShell.

Cmdlets like Get-NetIPAddress aren't actually part of PowerShell - they're part of the underlying OS, in this case, Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2.  They rely on functionality in specific OS versions, so they're bundled with the OS, and not the management framework.

So, unfortunately, the answer to your question is that there's nothing you can do to get Get-NetIPAddress to work on Windows 7, short of upgrading to Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know what structure the `Get-NetIPAddress` cmdlet returns its data in, but if you're looking for a way to retrieve IP settings you can use WMI and the [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394217.aspx):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'IPEnabled = True'
```

The [System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.networkinformation.aspx) has a number of classes you can use to retrieve the same kind of information:

```
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces() `
    | ForEach-Object { $_.GetIPProperties() } `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'UnicastAddresses';
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been very frustrated with the lack of this particular cmdlet in Pre-Win8, Server2012 PS. One way of getting your TCPIP setting into PS for manipulation is to set a variable to the output of an ipconfig command for example: 
`$ipconf = ipconfig`

This will give you most of the same information that get-netipaddress will give you.

The next command will filter out all but the IP addresses-

`$ipconf = $ipconf -match "IPv"`

But this will return something formatted like :

`IPv4....................... : 192.168.0.1`

If you want to get just the IP address:

`$ipconf = $ipconf.split(":")[1]`

Comment: **`((ipconfig) -match "IPv").split(":")[1].trim()`**

Comment: this answer should be the accepted one.
anyway - one small comment - better specify which version of ip to match - for case both are on  (IPv4/IPv6)

Answer (score 1):

`Get-NetIPAddress` is not part of powershell but of windows server itself. I recommend running windows server in a VM and doing your studies from there.

You can download a 180 day evaluation ISO or VHD from [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh670538.aspx) and use the trial to do your studies.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that's probably what i'll do, use a virtual disk. However i still wonder... is there any similar or (near to) commands in early versions of PS to get/set ip addresses in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Ran across `Get-NetIPAddress` first, but need it to work across Win7, too. `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` seems to give more than enough.

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {($_.IPEnabled -eq $true) -and ($_.DHCPEnabled -eq $true)} | Select IPAddress).IPAddress
```

That is an example of my use case. `IPEnabled` seems to filter out virtual/"fake" adapters, and `DHCPEnabled` to find non-statically assigned addresses (because these are mostly client machines and don't care about edge cases). Basically, to get "the most real IP" possible.